# running time of changetoBinary algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, big-o

I designed an algorithm to convert powers of 10 to binary assuming that n is a power of 2.
I used Gauss's Method to use the fast running time of this nice method. For that I divide n over 2 and send it to Gauess method as follow:

```
changetoBinary(n)
if n=1
    return binary of 10 which is 1010

else

 return gauess(n/2,n/2)
```

It is clear that Guess method will first divide and then conquer and then combine. At the end we have the number changed to binary. Now my question is about the running time of algorithm: my understanding is that since Guess running time is Theta(n^log3(base2)) we can say that the running time of this algorithm is also the same because most of the work is done by Guess.On the other hand when I try to find the recurrence relation I come up with T(n/2)+O(n) which is Theta(n) so which one is correct?Am I missing sth in my calculation that I get to contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

recurrence relation of your algorithm is not
T(n)=T(n/2)+n;

the complexity of your algorithm is O(1).
so you are right that complexity of gauess function will be the complexity of your algorithm.

if your algorithm would have been:
change_to_binary(n)
{
 change_to_binary(n/2);.....
}

then T(n)=T(n/2)
would have been your rec. relation.

Comment: Thanks for answering , I am wondering why the running time is only T(n)= T(n/2) because at the end it should add binaries for example 1010 and 1010 becomes (2^2*10+10)(2^2*10+10) and we at lest have 2 binary addition which take n(input size of that level)?

Comment: T(n)=T(n/2)+c;
and c=1 for algorithm "change_to_binary".

addition of binary is done is 'gauess' function and its complexity is already given.
Secondly, each function will add the binary no. and since, the parameter is reduce to half(n/2) of original(n) it will lead to input size of '1' bit at last call of function .

Comment: So just for clarifying my mind do you mean that the running time of this alg is Theta(n^log3(base2))?

Comment: yes, if gauess function has complexity "Theta(n^log3(base2))" then your whole algorithm will have complexity "Theta(n^log3(base2))".